# Can somebody recognize this programming language?

Tags: program-analysis

I'm curious in which programming language or script language is this written,
any idea?

```
[Dashboard\Alfa Romeo\147 93C86]

Size(280,270); // ширина и высота

Form
{
Form {
    Group("Пробег",35,13,120,50)
    {
        Digit(Distance," ",5,18,70);
        Label(lbkm,"КМ",90,20);
    }
    Group("Информация",5,80,270,45) 
    {
        Label(msg," ",0,18);
    }    
    Group("Описание",5,130,270,90) 
    {
        Label(lb1,"Калькулятор пробега для Alfa Romeo 147.",0,20);
        Label(lb2,"93C86 VDO 2001г.",0,35);
        Label(lb3,"Введите нужное значение в окне <Пробег>.",0,50);
        Label(lb4,"Нажмите кнопку <Применить>.",0,65);
    }
    // Picture(Logo,"alfa.bmp",190,17,0,0);
}

OnShow 
{
    // проверка дампа
      Var0 = ((@0x001 << 8)+@0x000;
      Var1 = ((@0x301 << 8)+@0x300);
      if(Var0 = Var1)
       {
        Var2 = (((@0x000 << 8)+@0x001) ^ 0xFFFF) << 5;
        msg.Color = 0xFF0000;
        msg.Bold = 1;
        msg = "Дамп ОК. Введите пробег.";
        Distance = Var2;
        }
       else
        {
        msg.Color = 0x0000FF;
        msg.Bold = 1;
        msg = "Неверный дамп!";
        Distance = 0;
        } 
}

OnApply {
    Var5 = 0;
    Var2 = Distance;
    Var7 = Var2 >> 5 & 65535 ^ 0xFFFF;
    if(Var2 > 999900) {Var5 = 1;}
    if(Var2 < 100)   {Var5 = 1;}
    if(Var5 != 0)
    {
        msg.Color = 0x0000FF;
        msg.Bold = 1;
        msg = "Пробег должен быть от 100 до 999900 км";
    }
    else
    {
        Var3 = 0x00;
        while(Var3 != 0x20)
        {

            @Var3 = Var7 >> 8 & 255;
            @Var3.mismatch = 1;
            Var3 = Var3 + 1;
            @Var3 = Var7 & 255;
            @Var3.mismatch = 1;
            Var3 = Var3 + 1;
            Var6 = Var7 * 2;
            Var7 = (Var6 >> 16 + Var6) & 65535;
            msg.Color = 0xFF0000;
            msg.Bold = 1;
            msg = "Новый пробег записан.";
        }
        Var3 = 0x300;
        while(Var3 != 0x320)
        {

            @Var3 = Var7 >> 8 & 255;
            @Var3.mismatch = 1;
            Var3 = Var3 + 1;
            @Var3 = Var7 & 255;
            @Var3.mismatch = 1;
            Var3 = Var3 + 1;
            Var6 = Var7 * 2;
            Var7 = (Var6 >> 16 + Var6) & 65535;
            msg.Color = 0xFF0000;
            msg.Bold = 1;
            msg = "Новый пробег записан.";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Russian, definitely.

As far as I can tell somebody writes [here](http://www.cyberforum.ru/programming-theory/thread1934838.html) (in Russian, sorry) that it is a language of программатор, or programmer,named ["Тритон" - sorry, Russian again](http://triton-prog.ru). The language that looks very similar to what you describing can be found in their documentation (sorry, Russian only, I couldn't find it in English) [here](http://www.triton-prog.ru/doc/si-calk.htm) . I don't know if they invented the language: may be it is a copy of something else, but this is the closest reference I can find.